# Use Google Script to check non-active sheet onEdit, Send Webhook when blank cell next to filled cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I have been working on this for a few days but I am new to this and I am trying to glue things together from different searches.

Senario:

A spreadsheet with 3 sheets: sheet1, sheet2, sheet3.

sheet3 is populated by query and arrayformulas from sheet1 and sheet2(only column A).

When a new line comes over to sheet3 from sheet1 there will be the situation where column B has a value but column A does not. I know that the onEdit will not pick up from the query fill but it should from the change that I made to sheet1 that caused it. I might need a delay to give the query time to work.

I want that situation to be when I send out a webhook that will then create other automations.

The last automation created by that webhook will fill that blank value in column A to turn it off.

Here is what I have so far: The trigger is an installed onEdit since I need that for UrlFetchApp.fetch

```
function CC(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var autoSheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet3");
  var triggerVal = autoSheet.getRange(2, 1,autoSheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();

  for (var n=0;n<triggerVal.length;n++){
    if(!triggerVal[n][0] && triggerVal[n][1] != ""){
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("WEBHOOK URL");
    }
  }
}
```

I tried another method of using a formula in the sheet to set another column to "trigger" based on the same constraints but I could not figure out how to get the script to go through that column and test for that text either so I moved to this to try and take a step out.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: It's not real clear to me what your doing? But the code that you've shared works okay for me.  I wrote the if statement like this `if(!triggerVal[n][0] && triggerVal[n][1] ){
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("WEBHOOK URL");
    }` If you want to put some in colA after the URLFetchApp.fetch then put in in triggerVal[n][0] and add `autosheet.getRange(2, 1,autoSheet.getLastRow(),2).setValues();` after the loop. I'd probably have to look at your spreadsheet to help any more.

Comment: A formula can't activate triggers. Please add more details to clarify what do you expect that triggers the script and where did you get stuck.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have 2-3 sheets that feed into a bigger single sheet that has all of the information on it.. I want to run all of the automations (scripts, zapier) off of this one big sheet.

I know that the formulas can not trigger the script but I thought that if an edit is made on say sheet1 then a formula will fill sheet3 and also the edit will trigger the script to look at sheet3.

The situation that I want to send a Webhook to zapier to perform actions in other api's is when sheet3 col2 has info and col1 is blank